# how to display using inner join?

Tags: php, html

im still learning in php and i have this two codes

this is for the connection to the database:

```
<?php
include 'C:/xampp/htdocs/lumino/function.php';
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if(!$link)
{die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($link));}

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($link, DB_NAME);

if (!$db_selected)
{die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysqli_error($link));}

$sql = "SELECT product_database.prod_id, product_database.prod_name, product_database.prod_year, product_database.prod_price, product_database.prod_desc, product_database.prod_comp, product_database.prod_shop, ctg_db.ctg_name, product_database.prod_attr, product_database.prod_tag 
        FROM product_database
        INNER JOIN ctg_db
        ON product_database.ctg_id = ctg_db.ctg_id";


$results = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if(!$results)
{die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($link));}

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

and this is for the viewing of data:

```
<?php
        include 'C:/xampp/htdocs/lumino/func_view_item.php';
        echo '
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Item List</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">    ';
                    echo"<table border = 3 >
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Product ID</th> 
                                <th>Product Name</th> 
                                <th>Year Produced</th> 
                                <th>Price</th> 
                                <th>Description</th> 
                                <th>Company</th> 
                                <th>Shop</th> 
                                <th>Category</th> 
                                <th>Attribute</th> 
                                <th>Tag</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>";
                            while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
                                                {echo "<tbody>";
                                                    echo "<tr>";
                                                    echo "<td>". $record['prod_id'] . "</td>";
                                                    echo "<td>". $record['prod_name'] . "</td>";
                                                    echo "<td>". $record['prod_year'] . "</td>";
                                                    echo "<td>". $record['prod_price'] . "</td>";
                                                    echo "<td>". $record['prod_desc'] . "</td>";
                                                    echo "<td>". $record['prod_comp'] . "</td>";
                                                    echo "<td>". $record['prod_shop'] . "</td>";
                                                    echo "<td>". $record['ctg_name'] . "</td>";
                                                    echo "<td>". $record['prod_attr'] . "</td>";
                                                    echo "<td>". $record['prod_tag'] . "</td>";
                                                    echo "</tr>";
                                                echo "</tbody>";}
                                                echo '
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>' ; 
        ?>
```

the view function does not seem to output the data.
can you please help me display data from the database?
thank you

Comment: Did you echo and exit your query and then run it in phpmyadmin ?

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Checked your error log? Do you have display_errors turned on? Have you checked if you query actually returns any results?

Comment: Make sure you are connected to the database. Check if you really are.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysqli-connect.php `$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");` put ur DB in the connect

Comment: try moving `mysqli_close($link);` **after** your `while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($results))`.

Comment: @KikiTheOne - The way the OP has done it is totally valid, so changing that won't solve anything.

Comment: @Sean - Since the OP already has fetched the result, it's safe to close the connection before `mysqli_fetch_array()`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson where has the OP fetched the results? As far as I know, [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) *performs a query on the database*. The result is not fetched until they call `mysqli_fetch_array()`.

Comment: @Sean - Sorry. Bad phrasing. `mysqli_query()` actually _gets_ the results from the database. `mysql_fetch_array()` is only fetching the result as array from the `mysqli_result`-class. And for that, you don't need the connection. I've tested it and it does work.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson got it. I learned something new, thx.